# Does Arch Linux support a high DPI laptop display?

Tags: laptop, display, arch-linux, xfce, high-dpi

I'm currently looking for a laptop to use with Arch Linux and XFCE, and have a question about Arch's support for, or compatibility with, high-DPI (retina-style) displays.  Does Arch support this type of display out-of-the-box?  If not, what hoops would I need to jump through to use that type of display with Arch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found there to be less problems with HiDPI on Linux than expected. Most modern DEs will scale correctly, many have a config option that simply doubles the size of everything if the scaling does not work by default. I currently am running a HiDPI laptop with XFCE and GNOME no problems